# contradiction between filtering noises versus identifying important noise

Tags: signals, filtering

I was given this question for my exam, and I could not find a good answer for it online. I am wondering if some one can help me with it please!
The question is:
When filtering sensor data there is contradiction between filtering noises versus identifying important noise which could be meaningful. Describe an outline of an algorithmic approach which could be useful for identifying when a noise should be filtered versus when it could represent an interesting value of interest. Many thanks in advance.

Comment: If you have noise, there will always be information loss.
A simple approach is to use low pass filter, In many use cases, the idea is it will affect noise much more than sensor data. The optimal approach is to use Kalman Filter (at least for linear cases), it can be adapted for non linear cases, but is no longer mathematically optimal. The difference can then be analyzed to see if follows some other pattern

Comment: Thnks for your response. Actually I am not looking for noise reduction techniques. Suppose, the noise is detected but actually it contains useful information. How can I verify that this noise is useful to process.
for instance, assume we are using an accelerometer attached to the foot, when climbing a mountain. the walking patterns collected in accelerometer signal will be distorted due to uneven surface. A noise reduction technique will remove these effects from the signal.

Comment: but assume we are looking for surface characteristics from walking signal and by removing anomalies we are actually losing information. therefore, the noise due to surface unevenness contained some information.
I am looking for such an approaches that can show me that the detected noise maybe useful and contain important information.